# Remove concerns from typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In typescript with react, I have the following situation:

```
    if (isEdit && !itemToEdit) {
        return <StepSpinner />;
    }
    ...
    ...
    return <MyComponent  itemId={itemToEdit.id} />;
```

`itemToEdit` definition is `itemToEdit?: Item;` (optional).
Typescript gives me an error: `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.
If I change the condition to `if (!itemToEdit) {`, the error disappear.

How can I tell typescript "trust me, this is not undefined"?
In my real world code I have many usages of `itemToEdit` and I don't want to use casting because those are points of failure.
Is there any solution to such case?

Comment: I assume you only try to use `itemToEdit` if `isEdit` is true? From your example you are not returning if `isEdit` is false (even if `itemToEdit` is undefined), which might be why typescript tells you there's no guarantee `itemToEdit` exists.

Comment: You right. Agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that itemToEdit cannot be undefined, you can use TypeScript's non-null assertion operator.

```
itemToEdit!.id
```

This simply tells TypeScript, trust me, it's fine.

Comment: Cool. didnt know that. I hoped TS would be claver and will be able to detect such conditions.

Comment: It can detect them using a type guard or if the object is built in code, but if the object is deserialized from a JSON string at runtime, TypeScript can't know about it at compile time. For that reason is is better to check for null types at runtime. You can use a tertiary `itemToEdit ? itemToEdit.id : null`. In the near future the null assertion operator should be available `itemToEdit?.id`, both of these being runtime rather than compile time assertions.